# How to filter out query results in RoR app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Have been working with RoR for a bit and I found a way to filter query results but I'm not sure I'm doing it right. As in any new language/tech, you become a kid script and I don't like it.

I have a controller that does this

```
@events = Appointment.scoped
@events = @events.which_user(current_user.id)
```

Then, in the Appointment model I have this code to keep only appointments for the given userid:

```
scope :which_user, lambda {|user_id| {:conditions => ["user_id = ?", user_id]}}
```

I sort of figured this code out of an example, but I'm still barely able to understand it. Can someone tell me a bit how does the Ruby magic work for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as with most Ruby on Rails stuff, there's all kinds of magic going on behind the scenes to make it work, but basically:

```
@events = Appointment.scoped
```

Creates a representation of an SQL query, but doesn't execute it.  This lets you modify your query - if you need to - before running it.  The default query is to select all the fields of all the rows in the table.

```
scope :which_user, lambda {|user_id| {:conditions => ["user_id = ?", user_id]}}
```

Defines a way to add conditions (or an ordering, or whatever) to an SQL query.  So if you call `somequery.which_user(3)`, it returns another query that has all the restrictions of `somequery` with the additional restriction that `user_id` has to equal `3`.

```
@events = @events.which_user(current_user.id)
```

Does just what I mentioned above.  Now `@events` is a query that will return all of the fields of only the rows that have the correct `user_id`.

And the final bit of Rails magic is that these queries are automatically executed and transformed into arrays of records when you use them.  It's functions like `each` that trigger this; if you want to iterate through your records, then you'll need some actual records to iterate through - so Rails runs the query and gets them to you.

Hope that helps!  Let me know if I've left anything too vague.

**PS:**  There's also the default Rails method `where`, which works in a very similar way.  For simple conditions like this, it's probably easier than using `scope`:

```
@events = Appointment.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
```